# Scala : optimize collection operation

Tags: scala, optimization, collections

The operation is about to calculate users Six Degrees relationships count.

Each user may have zero or many friends, table structure like this:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userId   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| friendId | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I get all relationship records from database,
and calculate as `Map[Long, Set[Long]]` which is every user's id mapping to user's friends id set.

```
val friendMap = friends.groupBy(_.userId) map { group =>
  group._1 -> group._2.map(_.friendId).toSet
}
```

Then calculate every user's Six Degree friends count:

```
val sixDegreeFriendCountMap = friendMap map { m =>
    val (userId, friendIds) = m
    val twoDegree = friendIds.flatMap(id => friendMap.getOrElse(id, Set())) --
        friendIds
    val threeDegree = twoDegree.flatMap(id => friendMap.getOrElse(id, Set())) --
        friendIds -- twoDegree
    val fourDegree = threeDegree.flatMap(id => friendMap.getOrElse(id, Set())) --
        friendIds -- twoDegree -- threeDegree
    val fiveDegree = fourDegree.flatMap(id => friendMap.getOrElse(id, Set())) --
        friendIds -- twoDegree -- threeDegree -- fourDegree
    val sixDegree = fiveDegree.flatMap(id => friendMap.getOrElse(id, Set())) --
        friendIds -- twoDegree -- threeDegree -- fourDegree -- fiveDegree

    val all = friendIds ++ twoDegree ++ threeDegree ++ fourDegree ++ fiveDegree ++ sixDegree

    userId -> all.size
}
```

I could get the result from `sixDegreeFriendCountMap`, but the problem is calculate every user cost 500 ms, and I have 300,000 users.

So this programming running more than 40 hours.

Any suggestion about the algorithm of `sixDegreeFriendCountMap`?

Comment: I almost sure that's the task for [graphx](http://spark.apache.org/graphx/) not for dataframe